# I get exception when I pass empty datetime value to sqlserver via VBA

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I'm trying to export some tables from EXCEL 2013 to my SQL Server 2017 Database via VBA ADO. All works fine, except when the datetime cell contains an empty value and then I get an exception. I tried to replace the values with `NULL`, `1900-01-01`, `''`,`((0))` but I always get SYSTEM ERROR `&H80040E07`

```
 NUM_COURIER = rg.Cells(i, 3)
 DATE_DEPART = rg.Cells(i, 4) 'DATETIME
 DATE_RECEPTION = rg.Cells(i, 5) 'DATETIME

 If DATE_DEPART = "" Then DATE_DEPART = "''" Else DATE_DEPART = "'" & DATE_DEPART & "'"
              If DATE_RECEPTION = "" Then DATE_RECEPTION = "''" Else DATE_RECEPTION = "'" & DATE_RECEPTION & "'"

              StrQuery = "INSERT INTO  COURIER (NUM_COURIER_BANQUE,DATE_DEPART_BANQUE,DATE_RECEPTION_BANQUE) VALUES('" & NUM_COURIER & "'," & DATE_DEPART & "," & DATE_RECEPTION & ")"

Set rs = query(conn, StrQuery)
```

Comment: Your SQL is wide open to injection. if you Parametrise your query, then the problem  likely go away as well.

Comment: you are getting error because you are trying yo save  '' in the date column. Pass NULL in date column instead of ''

Comment: it is a datetime column BTW , and I have tryed NULL but it did not work i get the same error

Comment: Are the columns Nullable?

Comment: yes of course , they accept null values

Comment: Stupid question: you have set the fields to `NULL`, not `'NULL'` (see the quotes?), right? Could you please add a `Debug.Print StrQuery` and add to your question the result you get from the immediate window, for the few things you have tried?

Comment: Now that I think about it: I quite don't remember what happens with the way you assign your variables on the first 3 lines of the code you posted. Could you please make sure to always have `... = rg.Cells( ... ).Value` or `... = rg.Cells( ... ).Text` (since your code looks French and you are not taking precaution with the date formatting, I suppose `Text` would be better)?